# Is it possible to create a Long Scroll Page (vertical) using only HTML and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

So I got this domain in a host site that allows only HTML and Javascript. The idea is to create a long scroll page, but the only way I find how to create it includes CSS. So I was hopeful that it can be done using only HTML and Javascript... Can it happen?

Comment: What does "long scroll page" mean? If it means a page that will show the scrollbar, just add a bunch of `<p></p>` paragraphs to the HTML...

Comment: Yes, now any other questions?

Answer (score 0):

Hard to imagine a host site that doesn't allow CSS.
But, if that's the way you want to go, you can define all your CSS as inline styles inside your HTML, or, you can apply CSS through Javascript.
With regular javascript, it would look something like this

```
var blah= document.getElementById('whatever');
blah.style.background-color= "green";
```

With Jquery, it would look more like this

```
$('#whatever').css("background-color", "green");
```

You can do this for any CSS properties you want to add.  Although, what Gavin Foster said is true, the overall height of your HTML document will adjust to fit the content so there is no additional CSS needed to make your page scroll up and down as long as there is content enough to fill up the page.  The problem is, without CSS, you can't give anything a height, and therefore, you might end up with  rather crowded-looking page and it might be hard to generate enough content to fill up the space you want to fill.  The technique described above can solve this issue.

Alternately, you can define your CSS inside your HTML in 1 of 2 ways.  You can either do something like this

```
<div style="background-color:blue;">This is a Blue Div</div>
```

Where you are simply adding all the CSS styles in the actual HTML tag for that element.  This will make for an HTML document that has more clutter, and you won't be able to use and re-use classes.

Or, you can essentially put an entire CSS document in the head of your HTML document.  Something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en"
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color: #00D1AC;
    }
    .whatever-class{
      height: 500px;
      width: 500px;
      overflow: scroll;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
... here, you put all the content of the body of the page
</body>
</html>
```

Where everything you would normally put inside a separate CSS document will instead be put inside of the `<style>` tag in your HTML head.  This way, you can use classes as you normally would with CSS.  This may be the easiest/laziest fix for your situation.

Comment: It's One.com, at first it was easy and fun to use, but to create more complex things it's impossible, so when I tried coding I found out that CSS wasn't allowed, so it's a pain.

Thank you very much. I'll try and use that method.